# how to create ensemble of convolutional neural network for human action recognition

Tags: python, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

Recently I'm working on an article and in the article author used ensemble of CNNs to implement the technique he proposed. I already know what ensemble of classifiers and CNN are and how to implement them but the term **Ensemble of CNN** is somehow hard to implement.

I've googled the term but there was no proper answer.Is there any tutorial or explanation that could be helpful to understand the term or any python implementation.

Appreciate any answer that could be helpful.

Comment: Which paper are you referencing? My guess is that an ensemble of CNNs is implemented similarly to an ensemble of any other classifier, whether by simple averaging of the final class probabilities, a weighted sum, or some other method.

Comment: This one [hybrid deep neural network for human action recognition](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494615005268)